# Can we use HTTP caching for navigation requests?

Tags: html, frontend, service-worker, cache-control

### What is Navigation requests

Navigation requests are requests for HTML documents made by your browser whenever you enter a new URL in the navigation bar, or follow a link on a page taking you to a new URL.

### Question

**[1] I want to understand if I can use `stale-while-revalidate` cache-control header instead of using a service worker to cache my inital HTML page?**

### What have I tried?

I tried to test this using Fiddler (to change the response cache-control header), but it did not work for HTML request, though it worked for other resources like JS for some websites.

**[2] Which makes me think if I have to change any other parameter also?**

Didnt work for HTML request
[image: Didnt work for HTML request]
It worked for JS files because we can see app.bundle was served from cache but was revalidated in background.
[image: It worked for JS files]

Comment: Why you want to use the header to cache the resource. If you are using service worker then you should use that to cache the resource.

Comment: @VimalPatel I don't want to use service worker because it can have huge boot time on low-end devices. And also HTTP caching is a lot easier than maintaining a service worker.

Comment: Http caching is not reliable and if you still want to go ahead with that, dont use service worker at all.

Comment: Ohh, can you please tell me why HTTP caching is not reliable?

Comment: you dont have much control over it and for that reason service worker was created to tackle the issues which was there . With SW you will have full control when and how to cache the resource and more.

Comment: Okay, that is true but SW is not good for users with a low-end device. Let's see if someone else knows if we can use HTTP caching for navigation requests.

Comment: Sw should be good enough. in practical SW gets executed in different thread not the current main thread.